# Looking to identify a book, probably sci fi,possibly Russian/Soviet author, mentioned cosmic flu

Tags: books, story-identification

I'm trying to identify a book I read as a kid ( born in 1977) where one of the characters mentions having /getting the cosmic flu which he/she describes as "feeling that everyone around you hates you ".